# Make "view more detail" work in Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-http

I've a problem having "view more detail" function work in my Angular app. This is pretty simple but i can't get the value of the details of a certain news that i clicked. This is how it works, first, you have a list of news and each news has a "view" button which can redirect you to a new page.  How can i display the value of details of a certain news? The problem is on the news-detail.component.ts

**news.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class NewsService {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }

getAllNews() {
    const authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth_token'); 
    const headers = new HttpHeaders() 
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json') 
    .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${authToken}`);

    return this.httpClient
      .get('http://sample/news/', { headers: headers })
      .map(
        (response => response));
}


getNews(index: number) {

  }

}
```

**news-list.component.ts**

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let newslist of newslists">
    <div class="card-header"> <button class=" btn btn-danger pull-right" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="onViewNewsDetail(newslist.id)">View</button> 
        {{newslist.category}}          
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        {{newslist.title}}   
    </div>
  </div>
```

**news-list.component.ts**

```
export class NewsListComponent implements OnInit {
  newslists: any;
  constructor(private newsService: NewsService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.newsService.getAllNews()
      .subscribe(
        (data:any) => {
          console.log(data);
          this.newslists = data.data.data;
          console.log(this.newslists);
        },
        error => {
          alert("ERROR");
        });
  }

  onViewNewsDetail(id: number){
    console.log(id);
    this.router.navigate(['news', id]);
  }

}
```

**news-detail.component.ts**

```
    export class NewsDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    id: number;
    news: number;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router,
              private newsService: NewsService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.route.params
        .subscribe((params: Params) => {
          this.id = +params['id'];
          // this.news = this.newsService.getNews(this.id);
        });
    }      
}
```

Comment: Do it like you have done the getAllNews?

Comment: @Kyrsberg. How can filter it? getAllNews will display the lists of news. I want to display the detail of the specific news that was clicked.

Comment: There is no endpoint for querying single news? Something like this `this.httpClient.get('http://sample/news/${id}')`

Comment: @Kyrsberg so how can filter it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont have endpoint for getting a single news article so maybe something like this will work for you.

**Service**

```
getNews(id: number) {
  return this.getAllNews().map((data: any) => data.data.data.find(news => news.id === id))
}
```

**news-detail.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params
    .subscribe((params: Params) => {
       this.id = +params['id'];
       this.newsService.getNews(this.id)
         .subscribe(news => this.news = news)
  });
}
```

Comment: It says property find does not exist on type object

Comment: `this.getAllNews().map(listOfNews => listOfNews.find(news => news.id === id))` is expecting that `getAllNews` method returns an array, but it is returning object

Comment: It doesnt to be response.json since httpClient parsed it as json

Comment: How can i address this?

Comment: I modified the answer again

Comment: It says property data does not exist on type object –

Comment: Can you logout the data you get from `return this.getAllNews().map(data => console.log(data))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153935/discussion-between-kyrsberg-and-joseph).

Answer (score 0):

Have you a routed like  { path: 'news/**:id**', component: news-detail.component } ?